# GitHub desktop branching and merging issues

Tags: git, github-for-windows

I was hoping someone might be able to help me. I am currently learning Git commands but for the moment I using the desktop version of GitHub. I am running into some issues with branching and merging and was wondering anyone could provide some insight into an issue I am having.

When I branch and carry out a large modification with various commits and commit messages I would like to be able to retain the commit history in the branch when I merge it back to `master`. At the moment when I merge, `master` will have the commits in its history (which I want too) but the branch lose all commit history.

I am getting pretty comfortable with the Git commands using PowerShell so if it would be possible to solve any of my issues with Git commands I would be happy to try it.

Comment: You are doing something really wrong if a merge changes the other branches history. This should not happen.

Comment: Its no so much that it changes the other branches history, its that it sends all the branches history with the merge to the master and does not retain it itself. No history is changed its just transferred. I do want it to transfer to the master but I need to keep a copy in the branch too.

Comment: Thats what I mean. A branch does not "transfer" its history. If you merge from branch X to branch master, branch X stays exactly the same, with all of it's history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of what your history probable looked like before the merge:

```
*--*--*--*--A [master]
             \
              *--*--*--* [myfeature]
```

Notice that `master` has no commits that `myfeature` doesn't have. (No commits have been added to `master` past the point that `myfeature` was branched off, commit `A`.) Because of this, by default Git does a fast-forward merge, which leads to history like this:

```
*--*--*--*--A--*--*--*--* [master,myfeature]
```

(As [mentioned by @tkausl](//stackoverflow.com/questions/39962173/github-desktop-branching-and-merging-issues-newbie#comment67205024_39962173), the history isn't transferred, only `master` is modified. Unless you deleted it afterwards, `myfeature` should not have changed.)

My assumption is that you want your history to look more like this:

```
*--*--*--*--A------------* [master]
             \          /
              *--*--*--* [myfeature]
```

To do that, you have to do the merge like this:

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff myfeature
```

If you want to undo your fast-forward merge and redo it as a `--no-ff`, do:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard A
git merge --no-ff myfeature
```

---

To figure out the commit hash for `A`, and to ensure that this is what happened, inspect the output of:

```
git log --all --oneline --decorate --graph
```

Comment: Hi Scott, sorry for posting two questions. I have only used stackoverflow once before so I wasn't aware of that rule. I will ensure I do not do it in the future. Thank you very much for your reply to my question, your answer is exactly what I was looking for and has helped a great deal

Comment: Just used all this info to correct some repositories I am working on and it was so useful. Thank you again for this. Also the extra section on how to redo a merge as a no-ff was above and beyond :D

Answer (score 1):

**You may be looking for `git rebase`**

When you rebase, git essentially imagines that you branched off from the main branch (e.g. master) later than you actually did. It brings master up-to-date and then automatically applies your branch's changes to this version.

There might be clashes if the files you've been working on have also changed since you branched but the rebase process lets you check over both sets of changes and choose the correct ones.

When you push these changes, you'll be rewriting history so you'll need to `git push --force`. Please be careful - This command can be dangerous as it might effortlessly overwrite your colleagues' code etc.

More info: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing